# How to find UPPER case characters in a string and replace them with a space with SQL or SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, replace

I have a column which has string values with mixed upper and lower case characters like (AliBabaSaidHello). I want to use this column values for my SSRS table cell headers like (Ali Baba Said Hello). First, I like to find each UPPER case letter and add space to it.

Answer (score 2):

Ascii 65-90 tip was helpful for creating below code for a function:

```
       declare @Reset bit;
       declare @Ret varchar(8000);
       declare @i int;
       declare @c char(1);

       select @Reset = 1, @i=1, @Ret = '';
       while (@i <= len('AliBabaSaidHello'))
       select @c= substring('AliBabaSaidHello',@i,1),
              @Reset = case when ascii(@c) between 65 and 90 then 1 else 0 end,
              @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset=1 then ' ' + @c else @c end,
              @i = @i +1     

       select @Ret
```

Thanks all, after Reading all the answers, I created this flexible and very efficient function:

```
FUNCTION dbo.UDF_DelimitersForCases (@string NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len INT = LEN(@string)
        ,@iterator INT = 2 --Don't put space to left of first even if it's a capital
    ;

    WHILE @iterator <= LEN(@string)
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]',SUBSTRING(@string,@iterator,1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @string = STUFF(@string,@iterator,0,@Delimiter);
            SET @iterator += 1;
        END
        ;

        SET @iterator += 1;
    END

    RETURN @string;
END
;
GO
```

Example:
**SELECT dbo.udf_DelimitersForCases('AliBabaSaidHello','_');**
Returns **"Ali_Baba_Said_Hello"** (no quotes).

Answer (score 1):

get chars one by one like "A" , "l" , "i", and look whether returning value of method `ascii('&i_char')` is between *65* and *90*, those are "**capital letters**".
( `ascii('A')=65(capital), ascii('l')=108(non-capital), ascii('i')=105(non-capital)` )

Comment: using Barbaros's hint, I was able to code a solution.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock please look at [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/ascii.php)

Comment: Not so fast @AnthonyHancock. What Barbaros posted may not be a complete solution but I think the ASCII 65-90 tip was helpful not just for putting together a solution - it can be used to produce a rbar-free high-performing solution. Note the code that I put together.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case sensitive` collation for your qry and combine with like **for each of character**. When you itterate characters you can easily replace upper characters for upper char + space.

```
WHERE SourceText COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI like '[A-Z]'
-- or for variable @char COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI = upper(@char)
```

The important in Latin1_General_**CS**_AI where "CS" is Case sensitive.

Comment: This would have been the route I would suggest, however I'm getting really weird results where only lowercase A is excluded when doing character by character comparison. Had to change to LIKE 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ'. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Add your string and like pattern and i will explain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this reusable for some reason, here's the code to make a user function to call.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS udf_SpacesforCases;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION udf_SpacesForCases (@string NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len INT = LEN(@string)
        ,@iterator INT = 2 --Don't put space to left of first even if it's a capital
    ;

    WHILE @iterator <= LEN(@string)
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]',SUBSTRING(@string,@iterator,1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @string = STUFF(@string,@iterator,0,' ');
            SET @iterator += 1;
        END
        ;

        SET @iterator += 1;
    END

    RETURN @string;
END
;
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_SpacesForCases('AliBabaSaidHello');
```

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that involves a scalar user defined function and/or a loop will not perform as well as a set-based solution. This is a cake walk using using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(1000) = 'AliBabaSaidHello';

SELECT newString = 
( SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN ASCII(token) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 AND position > 1 THEN ' '+token ELSE token
    END+''
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@string, 1)
  FOR XML PATH(''));
```

Returns: "**Ali Baba Said Hello**" (no quotes).

Note that the there is not a space before the first character. Alternatively, a set-based solution that doesn't use the function would look like this:

```
WITH 
E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(c)),
iTally(N) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (LEN(@string)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c, E1 d
),
nGrams(NewString) AS
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, N, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 AND N > 1
      THEN ' '+SUBSTRING(@string, N, 1) ELSE SUBSTRING(@string, N, 1)
    END+''
  FROM iTally
  FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT NewString
FROM nGrams;
```

Comment: I don't wholeheartedly believe that "Any solution that involves a scalar user defined function and/or a loop will not perform as well as a set-based solution." That being said I would also want to measure the performance of using the ASCII cast against a like [capitalalphabet]. It should be fairly simple to generate a random sequence of say, 1 million strings with various capitalization and see whether your solution or mine performs better?

Comment: As an aside, I'm really not good at using the XML stuff so I'm going to use your example to learn more about that, so thank you for helping me learn.

Answer (score 0):

The APL approach is to split the input into characters, pad the characters as needed, then reassemble the string. In T-SQL it would look rather like this:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample  VarChar(32) );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values ( 'AliBabaSaidHello' ), ( 'MeshMuscleShirt' );
select * from @Samples;

-- Stuff it.
with
  Ten ( Number ) as ( select Number from ( values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ) as Digits( Number ) ),
  TenUp2 ( Number ) as ( select 42 from Ten as L cross join Ten as R ),
  TenUp4 ( Number ) as ( select 42 from TenUp2 as L cross join TenUp2 as R ),
  Numbers ( Number ) as ( select Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) from TenUp4 ),
  Characters ( Sample, Number, PaddedCh ) as (
    select S.Sample, N.Number, PC.PaddedCh
      from @Samples as S inner join
        Numbers as N on N.Number <= Len( S.Sample ) cross apply
        ( select SubString( S.Sample, N.Number, 1 ) as Ch ) as SS cross apply
        ( select case when N.Number > 1 and ASCII( 'A' ) <= ASCII( SS.Ch ) and ASCII( SS.Ch ) <= ASCII( 'Z' ) then ' ' + Ch else Ch end as PaddedCh ) as PC )
  select S.Sample,
    ( select PaddedCh from Characters where Sample = S.Sample order by Number for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ) as PaddedSample
    from @Samples as S
    order by Sample;
```

Comment: This looks extremely inefficient compared to what @alanburstein submitted. Also I can't help wondering if you are referencing Hitchhiker's Guide with the "select 42" parts.

Comment: Yup, the performance is dismal, though probably adequate for headers in SSRS. It really was a flashback to an APL course in a prior millennium. ("Find all occurrences of string Alpha within string Beta." Efficiency was not a concern.) As for `42`, it's my placeholder of choice (even if it isn't The Answer) to indicate that I thought about what was needed and the answer was something syntactically satisfying and semantically unimportant. Now say "mesh muscle shirt" 10 times quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (quite verbose) might be:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('AliBabaSaidHello' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'A',' A'),'B',' B'),'C',' C'),'D',' D'),'E',' E'),'F',' F'),'G',' G'),'H',' H'),'I',' I'),'J',' J'),'K',' K'),'L',' L'),'M',' M'),'N',' N'),'O',' O'),'P',' P'),'Q',' Q'),'R',' R'),'S',' S'),'T',' T'),'U',' U'),'V',' V'),'W',' W'),'X',' X'),'Y',' Y'),'Z',' Z')
```